# How to identify which chrome extension is opening spammy tabs automatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I've got a very strange issue.

Randomly, every now and then, random websites will be opened up via new chrome tabs.

These websites appear to have some sort of thing in the URL relating to 'ad.strk' but then eventually redirect back to a clone of the last page I actioned.

For example, if I click on a movie in Netflix or NowTV (and many other random sites), a new tab is opened with that weird URL mentioned above, but then it directs back to the base NowTV/Netflix homepage.

Any idea what could be causing this?

It ONLY happens on Chrome. No issues of this on Opera GX, Firefox or Edge.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to disable all of your add-ons and plugins in Chrome, then enable them one at a time and test for the behavior. Even if you find one plugin doing this, make sure to test all of the plugins and add-ons, because if you've installed one plugin that does this, there's a good chance you've installed more than one that does it.